# chromium gyp config failure on linux

Tags: linux, chromium, gyp

I am trying to build chromium on linux but at the moment I fail at the command:

> GYP_GENERATORS="ninja" build/gyp_chromium

I get the following error:

> Updating projects from gyp files...
>   gyp: conditions chromecast==1 must be length 2 or 3, not 4 while loading dependencies of /home/code/git/src/base/base.gyp while loading dependencies of /home/code/git/src/build/all.gyp while trying to load /home/code/git/src/build/all.gyp

I couldn't find any solution on the net...
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to run build/gyp_chromium. In fact, on Linux, you should now be using GN, which is a new and improved meta build system replacing GYP.

The basic steps from the beginning are:

1. Install depot_tools
2. fetch chromium
3. (In your Chromium src dir) ./build/install-build-deps.sh
4. gclient runhooks
5. gn gen out/Default
6. ninja -C out/Default chrome

Once you're already set up, the update - build cycle looks like this:

1. git fetch && git checkout origin/master && gclient sync
2. ninja -C out/Default chrome

You can get all the details here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code